# Google BigQuery Patent

Tags: google-bigquery, google-patent-search

I would like to request Google Patent data (BigQuery).

In particular, my aim is to obtain patent data, including,

```
  publication_number,
  application_number,
  country_code,
  publication_date,
  title_localized.text, 
  abstract_localized.language
```

for a set of two (connected) search terms, namely, `robot` AND `medicine` (example).

How should I define/structure the query? (No further restrictions or search characteristics apply).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you already know about the existing dataset - https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/10/google-patents-public-datasets-connecting-public-paid-and-private-patent-data - can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: Thanks. To search for specific terms, I apply:  << WHERE
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(abstract,
    "\\b(term1|term2)\\b") >> My question: How to change the OR ('|') operator to an AND operator?

Comment: REGEXP_CONTAINS() AND REGEXP_CONTAINS()